# JAVASCRIPT - SERVLET JSP : no parameters send. Upload files

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets, upload

I try to send a file from client to my server with XMLHttpRequest. The link is ok but my File isn't send. I can only send his value : c:\fakepath\xork.xls. So I can't work with this file. I don't understand why it doesn't work. I can't change the .jsp because it's not mine and it's integrate to other files. 
Can you help me to find where is my mistake ?

Thank you very much.

Javascript : (I think the problem is in my datafile.append)

```
function extractExcel(contextPath){
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var fileInput = document.getElementById("test");
var dataFile = new FormData();
if(fileInput.files.length > 0)
    {
        alert(jQuery("#test")[0].files[0]);
        dataFile.append('file',jQuery("#test")[0].files[0]);
    }
else{
    alert("Il y a rien du tout putain de merde de chien");
}
    xhr.open("POST",contextPath+'/followup/addBarcodeToListEPC.do?',true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
//xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readystate == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
        {
            alert("succes");
            //location.reload();
        }
    else{
        alert("error");
    }
};
xhr.send(dataFile);
//window.location.href = contextPath+'/followup/addBarcodeToListEPC.do?';
```

}

.jsp

```
<form id="displayFollowUpSerialNumberForm" name="displayFollowUpSerialNumberForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <table style="margin-top: 5px; margin-right: 10px;" class="tableFilter" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="color:black" align="center">
                        <bean:message key="rfidprod.label.EPC.title" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr >
                    <td width="40%"><bean:message key="rfidprod.label.EPC.left" />&nbsp;:&nbsp;</td>
                    <td width="20%" class="test">
                        <input type="file" name="test" id="test" size="15" accept=".xls" />
                    </td>                   
                </tr>
                <tr align="right">                  
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <table>
                            <tr align="right">
                            <td>
                            </td>
                            <td class="button_generic_big" onclick="extractExcel('<%=request.getContextPath() %>')" align="left">
                                <bean:message key="rfidprod.label.EPC.button" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>                       
            </table>

        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

And My servlet :

```
protected ActionForward process(ActionMapping mapping,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        ActionForm form) throws Exception {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        LOGGER.debug("Start process Welcome");
    }

    //Enumeration parametre = request.getParameterNames();
    //System.out.println( parametre );
    System.out.println(request.getContentType());
    System.out.println(request.getParameterNames());
    Map<String, FileItem> foundParts = FileHelper.getMultipartContent(
            request, "UTF-8", 100000);
    FileItem cgv = foundParts.get("test");
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com